# AMD compatible assemblers for Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I have an AMD CPU and I've been looking for an AMD compatible assembler. Is there any advice for me?

Sultan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD chips are x86-compatible.  A standard x86 assembler will be good enough.

Comment: For most purposes.  AMD does have some specific stuff of its own (3DNow, very slight differences in how it does 64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

The assembler that comes with gcc ([gas](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/)) should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most versatile assembler is [yasm](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/). But you can of course still use gcc’s intrinsics and inline assembly features for both x86 and x86_64 code.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that lots of ASM tutorials are MASM-based, maybe you'd like to give [JWASM](http://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html) a try. Yes, it also runs on Linux.